# How to use stringbuilder in another button action?

Tags: java

i have this string builder line

```
 StringBuilder resultKamera = new StringBuilder();
```

that is  written in a button action, how can i use it to another button action?

Comment: You could declare the `StringBuilder` outside your method, as a field of the class, and use it in both methods.

Comment: You would need to pass a reference into the other action (or give it visibility some other way).

Answer (score 0):

you must declare`StringBuilder resultKamera` into your class block and outside your method